# Craft 3 CMS Solo setting general Logo option

Tags: craft3, craft-features

I have installed Craft 3 Solo and it's installed on my local machine. I would like to know how can I get an option in Setting -> General to Logo (upload Login Page Logo).
[image: Upload Login Page Logo]

I am new to Craft, so would like to get a little bit of guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login logo option is only visible with Craft Pro’s rebranding options. So, if you need this, you’d need to upgrade to Pro (or give it a  try without purchasing it, if you’re on a [dev-domain](https://craftcms.com/guides/how-craft-license-enforcement-works#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain)).